# Contact Form 7 - add a div from website page into email template

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a website page with :

- a div with results of a search
- a form created with CF7.

I would like to include the specific div into my CF7 email templates.
Is-it possible ?
Thanks everyone !

Edit :
the products are the result of a user search.
They are then grouped in a variable "$all_fiche".

What I would like to do is include these result sheets in my email templates.

any ideas?
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Uby.jpg)

Comment: A link to the page would be helpful.

Comment: I work on local on my computer for know. I don't have a link.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of it?

Comment: There it is, edit